# Kotlin Data Type Syntax

Tags: kotlin

What does the following data type means:

```
() -> String
```

It is being used in the following context.

```
fun sampleFun(message: ()-> String)
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a lambda function, this code means that this is a lambda function that return a string:

```
() -> String
```

and here it's passed as a parameter named message:

```
fun sampleFun(message: ()-> String)
```

so when you call sample fun you need to add message parameter like that:

```
sampleFun(
    message = {
        "Hello" // this means that when you call message it will return this String
    }
)
```

take a look on this [link](https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/04_functional/02_Lambdas) if want to learn more about lambda functions in kotlin and how to use them correctly